# Reading data from a text file into a 2D array and getting out of bounds exception

Tags: android, android-studio, multidimensional-array, text-files, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been having trouble with reading data in from a text file to a 2D array. I am not too sure what the issue with the out of bounds exception is because I thought I initialized it correctly but I am not sure.
Here is my code.

```
 String [][] f_team = new String [20][6]; //20 and 6
int cnt = 0;
int cnt2 = 0;
String line = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
loadData();
}
public void loadData()
{
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("team.txt")));
        while(cnt<=20) {
            line = br.readLine();
            f_team[cnt][cnt2] = line;
            cnt2 = cnt2 + 1;
            if (cnt2 == 5) {
                cnt = cnt + 1;
                cnt2 = 0;
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Here is my logcat for the error:
05-16 17:33:29.119 26312-26312/com.jmac.jmac.footy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.jmac.jmac.footy, PID: 26312
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jmac.jmac.footy/com.jmac.jmac.footy.Pitch}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                      **Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20
                                                                         at com.jmac.jmac.footy.Pitch.loadData(Pitch.java:82)
                                                                         at com.jmac.jmac.footy.Pitch.onCreate(Pitch.java:74)**
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array has size 20, you can only access index [0;19]
you are accessing index 20 in your while clause

```
while(cnt<=20)
```

you have to put:

```
while(cnt<20)
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Wow thanks so much, for the longest time I thought I was reading in the data wrong...Anyways my app doesn't crash so it's a good sign. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your String array is `String [][] f_team = new String [20][6];` which has an upper bound of 19 (0...19). Your loop is `while(cnt<=20) {...}` which will take your first index up to 20 and out of bounds (20 > 19).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java start with 0. In an array of length 20, you can address from 0 to 19. Look your while statement.

```
while(cnt<=20) {
```

Change it to cnt < 20.

Besides that, you should do a for instead of that clunky while structure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        String line = br.readline();
        f_team[i][j] = line;
    }
}
```

That way you won't have to face out of bounds exceptions.